# Sending Email to outlook using gmail server in python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I am able to send email and attachments from gmail account to gmail and outlook account. But in outlook account I am receiving corrupt file without file type and without data whereas I am receiving email in gmail account without any issue (preview is also working in gmail receiving account).
How can I solve the problem?

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import imghdr
import ssl

body = """
this is first mail by using python
Thank you! python
"""
EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'xyz@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PASSWORD = 'xyz'
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
message = EmailMessage()
message['Subject'] = 'This is my first Python email'
message['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
message['To'] = ["abc@gmail.com", "user_name@company_name.com"]
message.set_content(body, 'plain')
with open("path_to_image.png", 'rb') as img:
    img_data = img.read()
    img_type = imghdr.what(img.name)

message.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image', subtype=img_type, filename='filename')
default_context = ssl.create_default_context()
print("sending...")
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port=465, context=default_context) as server:
    server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    server.send_message(message)

print("success!!!")
```

*user_name@company_name.com* **is my private company outlook email address**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the proper MIME type to specify the type of content. Replace `plain` with `text/plain` for the body and `image` with `image/png` for the image. That way outlook (or any mail client for that matter) will know how to present the body and how to preview the attachment.

Comment: Thank you @Brecht Sanders. This will solve my problem. For adding excel file what should be the maintype and subtype?

Comment: I am using:: ```message.add_attachment(excel_data, maintype='application', subtype='vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', filename='excel_file')```  Excel_data are coming from 'rb' mode.

Comment: the problem is in filename.  `filename = 'excel_file.xlsx'` will work. This will allow to save the file with extension.